# "No such file or directory" error on using open() system call in code blocks

Tags: c, linux, windows-10, codeblocks, system-calls

I'm trying to open a png file on code blocks IDE on a c program in windows 10 PC, But I'm getting "No such file or directory" error though I have the image on that folder. I've tried including the path a well but still I'm getting the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char *input_img = "Tamilar_valvu_logo";
    int input = open(input_img,O_RDONLY);
    if(input == -1)
    {
        printf("Error no %d\n",errno);
        perror("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try including the .png extension on your input_img string. So, make it ```char *input_img = "Tamilar_valvu_logo.png";```

Comment: Normally image files have an extension (like **.jpg** or **.png**), what's yours?
Often the Windows Explorer hides extension of files. You should add also the extension in order to open the file.
If the picture is put in the same folder as the executable you should be able to open it without the full path, otherwise you need the full path.

Comment: @Ben : Thanks a lot Ben the errors have been resolved but the image is still not shown though the program has been successfully compiled

Comment: @piertoni : Thanks a lot Piertoni. But the image is still not shown though the program has been successfully compiled

Comment: Try to append the complete code, maybe we can spot the error

Comment: You always have to include the file extension when opening. For example, if you open a text file, you must include the .txt. The code you've written has nothing to do with actually seeing an image displayed. Check out this video for displaying images. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OyQoPCp46o

Comment: @piertoni : I've appended the complete code Piertoni